# How can i resize a specific window after it's created?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp, directx, window-resize

I want to resize some game window (DirectX) after it has been created, the game window allows resizing by mouse from the edges. But i want to automate this because it's quite hard to do this by mouse: cursor is invisible at the edges and i must de-focus the window first to be able to resize by clicking at the edges. To be clear: i have no sources for this game, so i must make my own program to do this.

How can this be done? Or better: is there already existing programs to do these things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might be problems, but its better to try simple things first.

As your post tagged with C++ I suppose you're looking for WinAPI solution. Try this one:

```
int width = 640;
int height = 480;

HWND handle = ::FindWindow(NULL, _T("Window title"));

::SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! btw, what for those :: marks are? works without them too.

Comment: They are used to choose between a locally defined symbol and a global one. For example, if you have a class with a method that has the very same name "FindWindow" there's no other way to call WinAPI function: `class MyClass { void FindWindow() { blah-blah } void func1() { FindWindow() <-- call local one} void func2() { ::FindWindow() <-- calls WinAPI } }`